# add,delete,edit a row using bootstrap icons

Tags: jsp

here my coding.... I want to add a new row with the existing icons and edit,delete row by clicking bootstrap icons using ajax in jsp

When clicking add icon, the new row should be created below to that row and data should be added  into that row,

when clicking delete icon, the entire row must be deleted

when clicking edit icon, the user can edit the data and it will change in the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Employee Details</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\eclipse-jee-galileo-SR2-win32(1)\eclipse\work\table\bootstrap\bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\eclipse-jee-galileo-SR2-win32(1)\eclipse\work\table\bootstrap\bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form class="well form-search">
  <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query">
  <button type="submit" class="btn" ><i class="icon-search"></i>Search</button>
</form>
<div class="bs-example" id="parentdiv">
    <table class="table table-hover" id="t1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align="center">Employee Id</th>
                <th align="center">Employee Name</th>
                <th align="center">Employee Designation</th>
                <th align="center">Employee salary</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="e1"> 1001</td>
                <td id="n1"> John</td>
                <td id="d1">Chennai</td>
                <td id="s1">60000</td>
                <td> <form>
        <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="icon-edit"></i></button>  
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button> 
                </div>
                </form>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="e2">2</td>
                <td id="n2">Peter</td>
                <td id="d2">chennai</td>
                <td id="s2">40000</td>
                <td><form>
                 <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="icon-edit"></i></button>  
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button> 
                </div>
                </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="e3">3</td>
                <td id="n3">John</td>
                <td id="d3">chennai</td>
                <td id="s3">30000</td>
                <td><form>
                 <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="icon-edit"></i></button>  
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button> 
                </div>
                </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please update your question by showing your JSP code as well.

Comment: What's your question?